NGINX Ingress rule with 2 backend apps are not working in expected way
https://mycompany.com/myapp.svc
I have configured below ingress to route traffic between my 2 backend services. here my requirement is to access these 2 apps different endpoint over different context paths (eg: /testapp1/xxx to testapp1 , /testapp2/xxx to testapp2, and not matching anything to testap1 itself).
The first app is working with the below ingress rule, but when acessing the second app, https://mycompany.com/testapp2/ its giving a response, but when clicking any svc file inside it[eg: myapp.svc] ,its directing to https://mycompany.com/myapp.svc throwing error   as below. But when I am directly accessing the ip of the pod its working properly.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: myapp-ingress
  namespace: myns
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: mycompany.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: testapp1
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: testapp2
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /testapp2
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mycompany.com
    secretName: mycompany-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.x.x.x

Error
Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

